# How to read binary file from hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm now working on writing a parser for shapefile with spark. I take use of NewAPIHadoopFile to first extract binary records one by one from the original .shp file. The problem is that when the program takes file from local disk, it works. But when reading file from hdfs, the bytes flow I get from DataInputStream is no longer integrated with the original file. The exception is as below.

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at ShapeFileParse.ShapeParseUtil.parseRecordPrimitiveContent(ShapeParseUtil.java:53)
    at spatial.ShapeFileReader.nextKeyValue(ShapeFileReader.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1702)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/05/25 17:19:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at ShapeFileParse.ShapeParseUtil.parseRecordPrimitiveContent(ShapeParseUtil.java:53)
    at spatial.ShapeFileReader.nextKeyValue(ShapeFileReader.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1702)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Code in RecordReader is as follow:

```
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ShapeParseUtil.initializeGeometryFactory();
        FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)split;
        long start = fileSplit.getStart();
        long end = start + fileSplit.getLength();
        int len = (int)fileSplit.getLength();
        Path filePath = fileSplit.getPath();
        FileSystem fileSys = filePath.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
        FSDataInputStream inputStreamFS = fileSys.open(filePath);
        //byte[] wholeStream = new byte[len];
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStreamFS);
        //IOUtils.readFully(inputStream, wholeStream, 0, len);
        //inputStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(wholeStream));
        ShapeParseUtil.parseShapeFileHead(inputStream);
    }
```

And here is how I set my FileInputFormat

```
public class ShapeInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<ShapeKey, BytesWritable> {
    public RecordReader<ShapeKey, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ShapeFileReader(split, context);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I use IOUtils.readFully to test, the whole bytes array I get is good. But when using DataInputStream, the flow goes wrong. So I believe the file on hdfs is still integrated. Since my file is of only 560kb and there is only one file on hdfs now.I think it can't be assigned to multiple blocks.

I'm new to spark so maybe this is a naive problem, really thanks to who can teach me that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself by changing read() to readFully() when reading byte arrays for in each record. I'm still a little bit confused since the available() I get is exactly equal to the size of split. But if I call inputStream.read(), it failed to to read to the length I assigned.